# Access embedded Solr server from external application

Tags: solr, lucene

Is there any way to access EmbeddedSolrServer from outside current JVM? For example, to update indexes or review index stats ([Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/) is good tool, but I'd like to use something web-based).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EmbeddedSolrServer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/EmbeddedSolr) is not meant to be used like that. Furthermore, its use is not recommended anymore:

> The simplest, safest, way to use Solr is via Solr's standard HTTP
>   interfaces. Embedding Solr is less flexible, harder to support, not as
>   well tested, and should be reserved for special circumstances.

You can just run a `HttpSolrServer` against your index and access to it through http. Otherwise you can analyze your index using a specific lucene based tool, like the one (Luke) you already mentioned.

Comment: The page you linked also said, **" the Solrj Java API provides an EmbeddedSolrServer implementation. This is the recommended way to "embed" Solr into a Java application. It provides the exact same API as you would use if you were connecting to a remote Solr instance -- which makes it easy to convert later if you'd like; and by using it you can be sure you will be Using API calls that will be supported in the future."**. Your answer is not very clear at this & may definitely misguide people.

Comment: @user01 if you have a better answer than mine you can post it.

Comment: Nope, I don't have an answer to this & I am still not sure what's the recommended way or what's not recommended because the linked page itself creates confusion about *which `EmbeddedSolrServer` is recommended* & *which `EmbeddedSolrServer` is not recommended*. I 'm myself looking for a clarification on this..

Comment: @user01 I agree, it is not really clear. What I got in the past, at the time I answered, was not to use it, or use it only for development purposes but not on production. But to be honest I haven't been playing around with Solr for quite some time now, things might have changed, that's why I suggested to add information or a better answer if there is one.

Comment: Infact I did asked a question about this[http://stackoverflow.com/q/19110022/530153] today but didn't recieved very satisfactory responses. I'll try seeking guidance through the official mailing list or IRC channel.